# What happens if one Carrom Man and the Striker are pocketed on the first shot?

Tags: carrom

If one Carrom Man (C/M) and the Striker are pocketed on the first shot then what happens?

As per rules we have to return two C/M to the board, but only one has been pocketed.
Will the player have to return an additional C/M to the board later?